# Web api for generate key .net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Gettoken(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(model.UserName + ":" + model.Password));
            return Json(svcCredentials, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

hello every one,I want to generate key for basic authentication, the key generated on localhost but when its publish on iis, its not working [throw error, for reference i attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ZEj.jpg)

Comment: The attached image doesn't have the exception, it's the generic message displayed when exceptions cannot be displayed. You are going to have to change your code so that you can see what exception is displaying. Without that, this will be near impossible to solve.

Comment: Thanks Jeff,  I resolve my problem, this problem occur due to some attributes missing in Web config file...